# How to use a .ipynb file in another .ipynb file in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a fileA.ipynb and fileB.ipynb in the same folder which I had on my drive
the path is
drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/
...
In fileB, I want to import fileA
But I am getting error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fileA'